# APIs/Services to Generate Thumbnails of Document

Tags: thumbnails

We have a website, which allows users to upload documents (word, pdf, PPT, etc.).
We are uploading files to Amazon S3. So, all files will have it's own web URL.

For these uploaded documents, we would like to generate thumbnails. This thumbnail needs to be generated based on it's content (like Google document viewer).

Is there any Service/API, which generates thumbnails of documents by it's URL?

Thanks and Regards,

Ashish Shukla

Answer (score 1):

You could roll your own solution. I'm evaluating [2JPEG](http://www.2jpeg.com/) and it appears to support [275 formats](http://www.2jpeg.com/overview/list-of-supported-file-formats) including Word, Excel, Publisher & Powerpoint files. fCoder recommends running 2JPEG as a scheduled background task. The [command line syntax](http://www.2jpeg.com/overview/2jpeg-command-line-syntax) is pretty comprehensive.  I don't think it has the ability to process remote AWS files, but you could retain it locally temporarily, generate the thumbnail and then delete the local source file.

Here's a sample snippet to generate a thumbnail for a specific file:

```
2jpeg.exe -src "c:\files\myfile.docx" -dst "c:\files" -oper Resize size:"100 200" fmode:fit_width -options pages:"1" scansf:no overwrite:yes template:"{Title}_thumb.jpg" silent:yes
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also take a look at AWS Lambda.  In fact, this presentation from the AWS re:Invent 2014 conference shows a live example of using Lambda to generate thumbnail images.  This solution will be very reliable, and very cost-effective, but has the downside that you'll be responsible for maintaining the code, or debugging issues.